# github submodule url for specific branch does not work

Tags: git, git-submodules

i have a repository in our company's github with a .gitmodules file and the follwing content:

```
[submodule "mod"]
    path = mod
    url = https://github.company.com/user/repo.git
    branch = spec_branch
```

the problem is that this link always points to the master branch and not the specific branch i have declared. Github itself does not now that i want to the specific branch if i follow the link in github, always leading to the master branch of the module, that is logical and understandable but if i clone the repository and initialize the submodules with

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

every time it loads the submodules from the master branch and not the spec_branch.
i always must have to be first run the command:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

is this normal? or is there a way to avoid that silly behavior?

Comment: `branch` sets the remote tracking branch, not what commit gets checkout out in the working tree. The submodule's commit is tracked by the parent repo. If you want to change it, checkout the desired commit, and then `git add` and `git commit` from the parent repo.

Comment: but my repo is the master branch and i want to import the modules from spec_branch i dont want to switch the branch in the parent repo